# Change China tourist visa to work visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, china, visa-change

Is it possible for a Russian national to convert a Chinese visitor (L) visa to a work (Z) visa while in China? The visitor visa expires in February.

Comment: Updated with the requested info

Answer (score 1):

Typically not. Any conversions of L visas to Z visas need to be done outside the country. Most people go to Hong Kong for a few days to get it sorted out. You should get the Z visa paperwork from your company, then go to Hong Kong and apply. Usually only takes a couple of days, and you can turn around and come on back.

Comment: Any references to this?